# Why don't fire hoops blow out while spinning, but blow out when blown out?

Tags: physical-chemistry, combustion

My friend spins fire hoops and we're wondering why they don't blow out while she's spinning them, but do, when she blows them out one by one.

I don't imagine there's so much more CO2 (so much less O2) in our exhaled breaths that it would make a difference.

So it must have something to do with how the flame and air interact differently in each case.

Here's more information on what fire hoops burn on, from [A Primer for First Time Fire Hoopers](http://www.hooping.org/2013/01/a-primer-for-first-time-fire-hoopers/):

> There are two fuels that are safe for you and your equipment while
>   fire hooping. White Gas (Coleman’s fuel) and Pure or Extra-Pure Lamp
>   Oil (never the citronella stuff). White Gas burns hotter and shorter.
>   Lamp oil burns longer and less hot. You and your safety should both
>   practice fueling, lighting, and extinguishing one wick with your
>   duvetyne several times before your first burn until you’re comfortable
>   with the process. The flame is extinguished by fully enclosing the
>   wick in the blanket. Eliminate the oxygen to the wick, kill the flame.
>
> The most common method for fueling wicks is called “dipping.” You pour
>   the fuel into an empty paint can and dip each wick into the fuel. This
>   is NOT my preferred method for fueling hoops. For one, you risk the
>   fuel running down the spoke and onto the hoop (yes, where your hands
>   will be later). Second, it requires “spinning off,” where you spin the
>   hoop on your body to get rid of excess fuel. You do this so that you
>   don’t send liquid flame shooting off the tip of your wick into a crowd
>   or nearby greenery. But it also means that you’re pouring chemicals
>   into the ground.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make your hand into a fist and move it around as fast as you can, then blow on it, where did you feel more "wind"?

Comment: Huh. It's kind of hard to believe when something our body does is _stronger_ than something done by what seems like a (simple) machine / lever type of thing. I think you're right though, that that's what it is.